# What are these connectors from a Lippert RV leveling system?

Tags: connector

Can you identify these connectors from a Lippert RV leveling system?

[image]

Photo isd from etrailers.com

Comment: Can you measure the center-to-center distance between pins / holes?

Comment: Also, did you mean to write "Slippery" in the title? Or Lippert?

Comment: "Lippert " sorry

Comment: I don't have them. I am looking to add them to a harness that got cut off

Comment: Sorry to be an annoyance, but if you don't have the parts, I assume you didn't take the image, which means, by site rules, that you need to give credit to the source of the image. This is usually accomplished by embedding a link in your question.

Comment: @SamMorrill - Hi, As commented, the [site rule for references](/help/referencing) requires that an actual *link* is provided to the source page for the image. Thanks for adding the site name, but that isn't a link to the specific *webpage*. Please add the source page name (that's likely to be some kind of title) and its link. TY (FYI site rules here differ from typical forums - see the [tour] & [help].)

Comment: "I don't have them". But you have the mates then, the ones that these plug into, right? Post pictures of the mates, and measure their exact [pitch](https://forum.digikey.com/t/pitch-of-a-connector/172)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big one is almost certainly a [Molex Mini-Fit SR](https://www.molex.com/en-us/products/part-detail/428160212?display=pdf), probably 0428160212.

The small one looks like a [TE Economy Power](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=411-5899&DocType=SS&DocLang=Japanese), probably 1-1123722-3.

If you have dimensions or other views of the plug, the answer would be more definitive. Prepare for sticker shock on the tooling; the Molex crimper is $4400.